# My Low poly becomes smooth

Tags: sculpting

I'm follow a tutorial to create a low poly environment.  So I have to make mountains... I go to Sculpt Mode and activate Dyntopo [ resolution : 7.00 / Refine method : Subditive Collapse / Detailling : Constant Detail] and when i try to do a picks It becomes smooth.[image]

Comment: Please don't take photos of your screen with your phone, learn how to use you operating system's screenshot functionality.

Comment: @Sazerac As well as system screenshot options, blender has its own [screenshot ability](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/info/screen_capture.html). Note that 2.80 has dropped the shortcut for this but it is still in the window menu.

Comment: On top of that, there are dozens of free screenshot tools out there for every operating system. Taking "screenshots" with phones seems to become a new trend here...

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic topology has an option to enable smooth shading, enabling this turns on smooth shading for the entire mesh.

[image: dynamic topology options]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when following the tutorial. These settings seemed to work for me.

[image]

Comment: What settings? Please elaborate by editing your answer.